# How can I solve a problem that undefined reference to constructor and destructor function of my own class?

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote a simple program that uses a class with a constructor, a destructor and a data member. When I tried to initialize an object, the debugger told me that there was not a destuctor and a destructor.I tried it in Clion, VS2019 and VSCode. And I got the same result like 4). I don't know it occurs all the time when I have actually created the constructor and destructor.

Pls help me. THANKS!

**1) String.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_STRING_H
#define TEST_STRING_H

class String {
  public:
    explicit String(const char *cstr = nullptr);

    String(const String &str);

    String &operator=(const String &str);

    ~String();

    char *get_c_str() const { return m_data; }

  private:
    char *m_data;
};

#endif // TEST_STRING_H
```

**2) String.cpp**

```
#include "String.h"
#include <cstring>

inline String::String(const char *cstr) {
    if (cstr) {
        m_data = new char[strlen(cstr) + 1];
        strcpy(m_data, cstr);
    } else {
        m_data = new char[1];
        *m_data = '\0';
    }
}

inline String::~String() { delete[] m_data; }

inline String &String::operator=(const String &str) {
    if (this == &str)
        return *this;

    delete[] m_data;
    m_data = new char[strlen(str.m_data) + 1];
    strcpy(m_data, str.m_data);
    return *this;
}

inline String::String(const String &str) {
    m_data = new char[strlen(str.m_data) + 1];
    strcpy(m_data, str.m_data);
}
```

**3) main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    String s1("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

**4) The result**

```
/tmp/ccCIK0hs.o: In function `main':
/home/Projects/test/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `String::String(char const*)'
/home/Projects/test/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `String::~String()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I guess you were typing and accidentaly posted the question instead? Please show us some code :)

Comment: You probably need to read about linking.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/580083).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "problems" with the way you used `inline` specifier. The fix is simply to remove the `inline` specifier from all `String` method definitions to make the error go away.

Let's delve into why your program is ill-formed.

I'll be using the points from [cppreference inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

> An inline function or inline variable (since C++17) has the following properties:
>
> 1. The definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed (not necessarily before the point of access).
> 2. An inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage (e.g. not declared static) has the following additional properties:
>
>    1. There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.
>    2. It must be declared inline in every translation unit.
>    3. It has the same address in every translation unit.

Ad 1) In simple words: If you have an inline function definition like `inline String::String(const char *cstr) { something }` you are allowed to call it from the same `.cpp` file. If you call it from other `.cpp` file, like you defined function in `String.cpp` but called it from `main.cpp`, that's invalid.

Ad 2) Your functions are not static, so this section applies.

Ad 2.1) If you have `inline String::String(const char *cstr)` in your `String.cpp`, you have to have `inline String::String(const char *cstr);` in class declaration in `String.h`. If you declare it with `inline`, it has to be `inline` everywhere, in `String.h` too. Right now in your code, in `String.h` it does not have `inline`.

The fix is to adhere to rule in points `1` and `2.1`. So either remove the `inline` keyword from `String.cpp` and have all your functions just be normal functions with external linkage, which is the normal way of programming.

Alternatively, if you have to have your functions with `inline` move all code from `String.cpp` to `String.h` and add `inline` to those member function declarations. Like the following code:

```
#ifndef TEST_STRING_H
#define TEST_STRING_H

class String {
  public:
    inline explicit String(const char *cstr = nullptr);
    inline String(const String &str);
    inline String &operator=(const String &str);
    inline ~String();
    inline char *get_c_str() const { return m_data; }
  private:
    char *m_data;
};

#include <cstring>

inline String::String(const char *cstr) {
    if (cstr) {
        m_data = new char[strlen(cstr) + 1];
        strcpy(m_data, cstr);
    } else {
        m_data = new char[1];
        *m_data = '\0';
    }
}

inline String::~String() { delete[] m_data; }

inline String &String::operator=(const String &str) {
    if (this == &str)
        return *this;

    delete[] m_data;
    m_data = new char[strlen(str.m_data) + 1];
    strcpy(m_data, str.m_data);
    return *this;
}

inline String::String(const String &str) {
    m_data = new char[strlen(str.m_data) + 1];
    strcpy(m_data, str.m_data);
}

#endif // TEST_STRING_H
```

Note that functions defined" inside" class definition are implicitly `inline`, so you could also move your function definition inside class definition.